# Python conditionally include class from command line

Tags: python, class, command-line-interface, stdout

I'm making a python script which needs to compare the stdout of two programs, it uses `subprocess` to run two binaries and collects their stdout. However, depending on the programs I am comparing the stdout format will be different. I would like to be able to define a "`output_collector`" class for each of my many programs which would translate the results to a universal format containing just the data which needs comparing, and then conditionally include this class from the command line.

My ideal interface to the program would be something like

`python3 compare_outputs.py --prog1 binary1 --prog1-collector ../path/to/prog1/output_collector.py --prog2 binary2 --prog2-collector ../path/to/prog2/output_collector.py`

Then in the main script do something like:

```py
data1 = collect1(prog1_stdout)
data2 = collect2(prog2_stdout)
results = compare(data1,data2)
```

Is this possible, or is there an obviously better way to acheive this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this using `importlib`

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("output_collector", args.collector)
output_collector = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["output_collector"] = output_collector
spec.loader.exec_module(output_collector)

...

result = output_collector.collect(...)
```